# Baking eligibility and start time

Tags: baking

I just registered as a new baker with a couple rolls. I can see the successful operation being made. How can I tell that I registered my baker correctly? When will I be able to tell when I am eligible to bake? And lastly, how long does it usually take to start baking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me try to take your questions one by one:

> How can I tell that I registered my baker correctly?

After the delegation operation happens, if you check tzscan.io with your baker address, you should see (in the right hand side) "Delegate Status: Active" and the Manager and Delegate address should be the same as your baker address (assuming you are not delegating to another baker).

> When will I be able to tell when I am eligible to bake?

You can check tzscan.io and click on the bakings tab to see when you have upcoming rights to bake and endorse. It may take a few cycles before you start to see this information populated.

> And lastly, how long does it usually take to start baking?

It will take 7 cycles before you can bake. What happens is that in the current cycle where you performed the delegate operation, a snapshot is taken at a random block height. The snapshot is used in (current cycle + 6 cycles) to determine your baking rights. This means it will take roughly 20 days before you will have rights to start baking and endorsing.

Good luck baking!

Comment: we should change of the answers revolving around tzscan to another block explorer.